# how to use multiprocessing to run one process per core in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import random
import time

def some_function(first, last):


processes = []

for m in range(1,16):
   n = m + 1
   p = Process(target=some_function, args=(m, n))
   p.start()
   processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
   p.join()
```

I would like the program to start only one process per CPU core and the following process should start after the completion of any of the process already running.
What are the changes that would  have to make the code .

Edit: one process per core: e.g. if there are 30 processes in total, and 4 CPU cores, At any point I want only 4 process(max) to be running. After the completion of any one of the process, the next process should start. By that way the number of process running should not exceed the no. of cores.

Comment: Place the `p.join()` right after the `p.start()`, although that this would make your program sequential. Can you please explain what do you mean by _one process per code_?

Answer (score 0):

If you call p.run() instead of p.start(), it will run only one process at a time, pausing until the process has finished running. With p.run(), calls to p.join() are not necessary.

EDIT: 
If you are trying to run a single process per thread on your computer (as the question is phrased), and you have 16 threads, there are no issues with the code that you already have.

Comment: p.run() makes the processes run sequentially. And does not make use of the multiprocessing capabilities.